# Error while join video files using Mencoder

Tags: php, mencoder

I am cutting and joining a video file using mencoder. But the output file is not playing in flv player in my website. But it playing in VLC media player without any error. What will be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i fixed this problem by joining the files in their own format using **MENCODER** and converting the joined video into flv using **FFMPEG**. Now it is playing well in my flv player present in my website.